# Как работает ассинхронность на уровне железа процессора

Tags: сеть, ассемблер, асинхронность, cpu, история

Например, такие операции как:

1. таймеры
2. ожидания ввода пользователя
3. работа с сетью

Процессор находится в каком-то `while(true) { ... }`? и постоянно проверяет нет ли новых данных. Буду рад также подробным статьям об этом. Интересно как это и в старых ЭВМ работало, так и в современных ПК.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Многопоточность#Аппаратная_реализация

Comment: "старых ЭВМ работало" Ну на пример самодельные типа "Специалист" или "Радио-86РК" на процессоре К580ИК80А (КР580ВМ80А) — советский аналог процессора I8080А  многопотчность не могли, интернета не было загрузка с аудиокассеты. Жесткий и оператива в одно лице

Comment: [Прерывание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: @wololo да я в курсе про прырывание